# Process files in folders with similar names

Tags: batch-file, installation

I'm writing a batch script to uninstall and reinstall a few programs.  My goal is to push this to multiple machines via Group Policy.

My question is about this first line:

```
Start /wait C:\PROGRA~2\STRUCT~1\spColumn\UNWISE.EXE /s C:\PROGRA~2\STRUCT~1\spColumn\INSTALL.LOG
```

In the `PROGRA~2` and `STRUCT~1` parts, it's pointing to `Program Files (x86)` and then the first folder that starts with `Struct`.  However, I've got some machines that have more than one folder in that location that starts with `Struct`, and I need it to point to the second folder in that case, I'd want it to say `STRUCT~2` instead for those machines.

Is there a way to make this run on machines with only one "Struct..." folder as well as the ones with two? Maybe adding if, then statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This becomes much easier when you use the full path name with spaces, and put it all in quotes.

```
Start /wait "C:\PROGRAM Files (x86)\STRUCTwhatever this is\spColumn\UNWISE.EXE" /s "C:\PROGRAM Files (x86)\STRUCTwhatever this is\spColumn\INSTALL.LOG"
```

To make it even better, I'd recommend using the `%programfiles(x86)%` environment variable, like this:

```
Start /wait "%programfiles(x86)%\STRUCTwhatever this is\spColumn\UNWISE.EXE" /s "%programfiles(x86)%\STRUCTwhatever this is\spColumn\INSTALL.LOG"
```

Comment: you know that `start` takes the first quoted parameter as title? Use a dummy title: `start /wait "" "%programfiles...`

Comment: Thank you both.  This worked for me.  I was assuming I could only use the  "PROGRA~2" (8.3 format?) for those commands.  

Am I able to use folder names with spaces whenever I need to as long as I put the path into quotations?


Is it good practice to use the double quotes as a dummy title whenever I have lines like this?

Comment: yes - use qoutes whenever you use a folder or filename with spaces. Best practice: don't wait for eventualities - ever use them. And yes - get used to use `start` with a (dummy) title - again, don't wait for eventualities.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if exist \PROGRA~2\STRUCT~1\ then Start
    :Start start /wait C:\PROGRA~2\STRUCT~1\spColumn\UNWISE.EXE /s
    C:\PROGRA~
```